# How to refetch graphql data for gatsby build?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

I have a gatsby-theme React application that uses `gatsby-source-graphql` to fetch the data from my back-end application. I had set the `refetchInterval: 20` in my `gatsby-config.js` file. My `gastby-config.js` file is as below

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: 'Gatsby Theme Mytheme',
    ...
  },
  pathPrefix: `/gtm`,
  plugins: [
    {
      ...
      ...
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-graphql`,
      options: {
        fieldName: `cms`,
        url: `http://127.0.0.1:7000/api/graphiql`,
        typeName: `CMSData`,
        refetchInterval: 20,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
  ],
};
```

When I run the application in the development mode (`gatsby develop`) I'm able to see (`console.log`) the changes made in the back-end CMS application after an interval of 20 seconds. But the changes are not able to see/display on the build (gatsby build). Therefore after the build, whatever I change in the backed it is not reflected in my front-end application. So how can I fetch the changes from the back-end application for my a gatsby build dynamically?

The component I use to fetch the back-end GraphQL data is given as

```
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby";

export function myComponent() {
  const cmsMenu = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    {
      cms {
        allMenus {
          edges {
            node {
              menuName
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  `)
  console.log("CMS menu from MenuProvider", cmsMenu); 
}
```

Comment: The reason the development build updates is that it watches for changes to help you develop faster. But when you run `gatsby build`, you generate a static site, and your data from Gatsby GraphQL queries is static by design - check out the docs on [Build Time and Client Runtime Data Fetching](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/data-fetching/). If you want to query a GraphQL API client-side, you can still use a library like Apollo, just like for a React SPA! Jason Lengstorf has a nice example at [jlengstorf/gatsby-with-apollo](https://github.com/jlengstorf/gatsby-with-apollo)

Comment: Thanks @RobinMétral .. As per your comment i think I'm in the right direction I'm following the instructions b Jason Lengstorf